# Creating a 2D Array from Another 2D Array (Python)

Tags: python, arrays

Hi so I am working with this 2D array that is formatted as a list of lists (here is a small sample unformatted):

`[[10017.0, 93454.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9.6, 0.0], [10024.0, 39374.0, 12.8, 28.8, 24.0, 9.829, 28.8, 62.4, 26.4, 30.4, 18.8, 4.0, 20.0, 16.0], [10024.0, 62807.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 38.0, 25.6, 70.4], [10024.0, 81405.0, 11.2, 12.0, 13.6, 7.2, 46.8, 25.6, 22.4, 8.0, 3.2, 12.0, 16.0, 27.2], [10026.0, 2964.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.717, 9.867, 11.683, 0.0, 5.417, 14.316], [10026.0, 29100.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.608, 1.531, 3.136], [10026.0, 39461.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 16.0, 0.0, 2.4, 0.0], [10026.0, 42209.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 16.8, 8.0, 2.4]`
...

The formatted version appears like this:

```
12230.000  116815.000    17.200     8.000    10.000     9.000     6.000    11.600     6.000     
12230.000  132820.000     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000     
12366.000  93769.000     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000     
12366.000  93961.000     6.400    20.000     0.000     0.000    12.000     4.000    16.000     
12369.000  40256.000     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000     
12369.000  48122.000    37.600    43.200    48.000    45.600    52.000    53.600    40.000    
12379.000  22775.000     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000    37.983
```

(Some of the columns were deleted for formatting purposes).
The array displays the Department ID in the first column, Employee ID in the second, and 12 columns for each month indicating how many hours each employee worked.

I need to design a function that looks at each employee row and calculates the cumulative hours worked by all employees in each department. In the case of the example data, I would have a row for Dep ID. 12230, 12366, 12369, and 12379 followed by the 12 columns for each month.  I would like this function to also output the data in a 2D array that is in the same format as a list of lists.  The function I have below works in that it does find the cumulative hours worked for each department, for each month.  However, it does not display the department ID and it only prints the data as individual lists. Any input on how I can modify my code would be greatly appreciated!

```
    def cost_center_sum (A):
        dep_list = []
        for row in range(0,len(A)):
            dep_list.append(A[row][0])
        myList = sorted(set(dep_list))
        for i in range(0,len(myList)):
           sum_list = []
           for col in range(2, len(A[0])):
               sum = 0
               for row in range(0, len(A)):
                    if myList[i]==A[row][0]:
                        sum = sum + A[row][col]
                        sum_list.append(sum)
                        print sum_list
```

Comment: The output of my function looks like this

Comment: [0.0, 0.0, 96.0, 128.0, 114.4, 61.6, 0.0, 32.0, 90.4, 50.4, 90.0, 87.6]
[58.4, 68.0, 72.0, 21.6, 18.0, 60.8, 45.6, 32.0, 54.4, 60.0, 71.2, 61.6]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like :

```
NUMBER_OF_MONTHS = 12
def collapse(A):
    dep = dict()
    for row in A:
        if row[0] not in dep:
            dep[row[0]] = [0.0 for x in xrange(NUMBER_OF_MONTHS)]
        for i in xrange(NUMBER_OF_MONTHS):
            dep[row[0]][i] += row[i+2]
    ret = list()
    for department in dep:
        x = [department]
        x.extend(dep[department])
        ret.append(x)
    return ret
```

Running it with your test data, the output is :

```
[10024.0, 24.0, 40.8, 37.6, 17.029, 75.6, 88.0, 48.8, 38.4, 22.0, 54.0, 61.6, 113.60000000000001]
[10017.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9.6, 0.0]
[10026.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.717, 9.867, 27.683, 18.408, 17.348, 19.852]]
```

Comment: Is there anyway I can sort the list so the Department ID is in ascending order?

Comment: Try using `for department in sorted(dep.iterkeys()):` instead of `for department in dep:`

Answer (score 0):

`hours = [sum(data_row[2:]) for data_row in data]`

Sorry, I misunderstood the first time, if you want to aggregate by column 1, get the unique values like this:

```
dep_ids = set(row[0] for row in data)
```

next initialize dictionary with each id:

```
agg_data = dict(id: [0] * 12 for id in dep_ids)
```

now you can run through your data and aggregate by id:

```
from operator import add
for row in data:
    key = row[0]
    agg_data[key] = map(add, agg_data[key], row[2:])
```

Comment: I'm sorry I'm still relatively new to Python. Where would I put that in my code and how does that help with the issue of listing the Department ID also. My function appears to effectively take the sum of all the hours of the employees working for a particular department